# Flutter : Rich notification for IOS

Tags: flutter, notifications, rich-notifications

I have added Notification extension service but IOS app not showing image in notification.[The errer after I added notification extension service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylMyi.png)

I am trying to handle image in notification using firebase notification.

The payload i use for firebase to send notification

```
{
    "notification": {
        "mutable_content": true,
        "title": "title",
        "body": "body"
    },
    "to" : "__token__",
    "data": {
        "image": "https://ilyarm.ru/assets/949163b5edd92aa1ec0379734-697x403.jpg"
    }
}
```